# Pattern Match a string for atleast two consecutive alphabets anywhere in the string

Tags: python, regex

In my python code i want to pattern match a string for atleast two consecutive alphabets anywhere in the string.

I used, `re.match(r'([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z])+',str)`

This matches a string for example **'abc'**, but does not match **'1abc'**. What is the mistake in my regex ?

Please Help
Thank You

Comment: What do you mean with 'alphabets'?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but you mean you must be ordered? As in, the regex shouldn't match if the string is `bca`?

Comment: It should match for bca. I just want to check for presence of atleast two consecutive alphabets anywhere in the string. By alphabet i mean upper or lowercase a to z characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `match` looks from the beginning of the string only. You should use `search` instead.

Also your regex is built to match an even amount of characters.

```
re.search(r'([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]+)',str)
```

Comment: A better regex would be `"[A-Za-z]{2}"`. Why keep the regex engine busier than necessary? The condition is true as soon as two letters have been found. But still +1 from me to counteract the undeserved downvote.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't quite understand what you want, but from the example provided one can see that you misinterpreted what re.match does. See [search() vs. match()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#search-vs-match) from docs on python's re module.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the updated question:

```
re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]{2,}', str)
```

Or simply like this if you want all alphanumerical characters (including the underscore):

```
re.search(r'\w{2,}', str)
```

To match really only alphanumericals:

```
re.search(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}', str)
```

The `re.search` might help you if you expect the match to be anywhere in the string, not just in the beginning.